# Trying to sync fast but get "flag provided but not defined"

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

Blockchain sync was taking forever, so I tried running get --fast after extracting keychain keys and the chaindata folder and the running get --fast. I get "flag provided but not defined".

How should I go about this. I'd like to sync the whole blockchain from scratch quickly.

Comment: Which version of `geth` are you using? If you run `geth --help` it'll tell you near the top of the output.

Comment: Hi Richard Horrocks thank you for reaching out. I'm using 0.9.38